# Disable Scrolling of UISearchbar that is added to UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have add a UISearchBAr to the UITableView to implement search functionality.

But after searching is done, the UISearchBar is also scrolling and disappearing along with the UITableView. I just want to know how to make the search bar static with only the UITableView scrolling...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your adding the searchBar to the tableView's headerView, which is why it scrolls along with the rest of the table. Try adding the searchBar to the view (NOT the tableView) and resize the frame of your tableView to be below the searchBar.